# Invoke child element event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, children

I need to invoke a function (toggleslide) on child `div` element with class name `pane` (parent div is `flip`).

I have a parent `div` and onclick I need a parent div element to show (slide) some content in child `div`. When I click on the `div` it will show all divs with child class `pane` so i tried add `this` to 3rd row `$(".flip, this").children(".pane").slideToggle("fast")` but it does not work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".flip", this).click(function(){
        $(".flip").children(".pane").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you want to only call `slideToggle()` on the `.pane` elements within the clicked `.flip`. In that case you do need to use `this`, but you need to use it as the primary selector within the click handler. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".pane").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.